# Redirect example.com to example.com/index.html in cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I have a domain example.com with it's corresponding cPanel.

I want the homepage to be example.com/index.html. What are the settings to redirect example.com to example.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .htaccess in your web root to redirect to the required file.